# how to put conditions in set comprehension?

Tags: set, list-comprehension

I have a code that goes thru each line in a file and split each line into words and put the first word into a set.

```
test = set([
    line.rstrip().split()[0].strip()
    for line in codecs.open(filepath, 'r', 'utf-8')
    if len(filepath) > 0
])
```

My problem is that sometimes the line can be an empty string and for some reason an

```
index out of range error
```

occurs. How can I fix that so that I can just skip the line where the errors occurs and continue to the next line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this?

```
test = set([
    line.rstrip().split()[0].strip()
    for line in codecs.open(filepath, 'r', 'utf-8')
    if len(line) > 0
])
```

(You had `filepath` instead of `line`.)

You probably need this, though, since an empty line will really be a "\n":

```
if len(line.rstrip()) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I actually did that. I added it to the filepath checking since I also need to check the file path. if len(line) > 0 and len(filepath) > 0 but there was still an error. I haven't tried that one though: if len(line.rstrip()) > 0

Comment: @user3009947 So is your code working now? If not, please share your current code and the exact error / stack trace you're seeing now.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just saw your edit. Please try `len(line.rstrip()) > 0` and let me know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: thank you very much @smarx. That worked! I already upvoted your answer but it won't reflect because I have less than 15 reputation.